# Mocking DBSet, EF Model First

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, nunit, entity-framework-5, rhino-mocks

As said in the title, I follow Model First method. So my Model classes are Automatically generated. If I want mock the `DBContext` derived `MyModelContainer` which contain `DBSets` of entity classes. Read some where that in order to unit test, you need to change it to `IDBSet`. Whether its possible to do it especially in a class that gets auto generated when I do "Run Custom Tool" is one concern. But as of now I modified it.

But the real problem is: when I try to Stub `MyModelContainer` to return a mock generated from `IDBSet`. Rhino mock is firing an InvalidOperationException: "Invalid call, the last call has been used, or no call has been made(make sure that you are calling a virtual(C#)/Overridable(VB) method."

Here is my unit test code.

```
MyModelContainer dbMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<MyModelContainer>();
IDBSet<Models.MyEntity> entityMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDBSet<Models.MyEntity>>()
dbMock.Stub( x=>x.MyEntities ).Return( entityMock );
```

The last statement is triggering the exception. I tried using the fake implementation of `IDBSet<>` specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463017/unit-testing-with-ef4-code-first-and-repository), But no luck!

I use MVC 4, Rhino Mocks 3.6. Any help will be appreciated.

**Update:**

After some trials and research, I found a fix. I changed the code to:

```
MyModelContainer dbMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<MyModelContainer>();
IDBSet<Models.MyEntity> entityMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDBSet<Models.MyEntity>>()
//dbMock.Stub( x=>x.MyEntities ).Return( entityMock );
dbMock.MyEntities = entityMock;
```

Now the `InvalidOperationException` is gone.
The test fails only due to `ExpectationViolationException` which should be normal.

As for auto generated Model class, it is found out that editing the `DbContext's` **T4 template (.tt extension)** will do the trick. Thanks to [Alan's Blog](http://mylifeandcode.blogspot.in/2012/10/unit-testing-with-mock-entity-framework.html)

*But I want to know why the previous code didn't work. Anyone?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 reasons are possible here:

1. `MyEntites` property of `MyModelContainer` is not virtual.
   In that case Rhino Mock can't stub this property at all. Then `dbMock.Stub(x=>x.MyEntities)` will fail.
2. `MyEntites` property is virtual, but has both public getter and public setter.
   Then notation `dbMock.Stub(x=>x.MyEntities).Return(entityMock)` is not allowed. You can see explanation e.g. [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.windows.devel.dotnet.rhino-mocks/1462).

In both cases the right fix is exactly what you did: use `dbMock.MyEntities = entityMock` instead of `dbMock.Stub(x=>x.MyEntities).Return(entityMock)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension method for Stubing (with RhinoMocks) IDbSet to return an IQueryable

```
public static class RhinoExtensions
{
    public static IDbSet<T> MockToDbSet<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable) where T : class
    {
        IDbSet<T> mockDbSet = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDbSet<T>>();
        mockDbSet.Stub(m => m.Provider).Return(queryable.Provider);
        mockDbSet.Stub(m => m.Expression).Return(queryable.Expression);
        mockDbSet.Stub(m => m.ElementType).Return(queryable.ElementType);
        mockDbSet.Stub(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Return(queryable.GetEnumerator());
        return mockDbSet;
    }
}
```

Then you can now stub the DbContext like this:

```
_db.Stub(p => p.Customers).Return(fakeCustomers.MockToDbSet());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension method for Substituting IDbSet (with NSubstitute) to return an IQueryable

```
    public static DbSet<T> FakeDbSet<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable) where T : class
    {
        DbSet<T> fakeDbSet = Substitute.For<DbSet<T>, IQueryable<T>>();
        ((IQueryable<T>)fakeDbSet).Provider.Returns(queryable.Provider);
        ((IQueryable<T>)fakeDbSet).Expression.Returns(queryable.Expression);
        ((IQueryable<T>)fakeDbSet).ElementType.Returns(queryable.ElementType);
        ((IQueryable<T>)fakeDbSet).GetEnumerator().Returns(queryable.GetEnumerator());
        fakeDbSet.AsNoTracking().Returns(fakeDbSet);
        return fakeDbSet;
    }
```

Then you can now stub the DbContext like this:

```
        var db = NSubstitute.Substitute.For<DataContext>();
        var fakeResult = emptyCustomers.FakeDbSet();
        db.Customers.Returns(fakeResult);
```