# Mocking DbSet<T> with RhinoMocks and EF6

Tags: unit-testing, dbset

I am getting this error when I run my test: System.NotImplementedException : The member 'IQueryable.Provider' has not been implemented on type 'DbSet' ...'
I saw [this blog post](http://romiller.com/2012/02/14/testing-with-a-fake-dbcontext/) on creating a fakeDbSet but that was before EF6. Is there a better way to handle this with EF 6?

```
[Test]
public void Edit_ShouldCall_DbContext_Entry()
{
        //arrange
    var request = Builder<EditGroupRequest>.CreateNew().Build();
    fakeDbSet.Stub(x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ReportGroupNameKey == request.Key)).Return(new MyObject());

    //act
    _sut.Edit(request);

    //assert
    _contextFake.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Entry(Arg<MyObject>.Is.Anything).Property(y => y.ReportGroupName).CurrentValue = request.Name);
}
```

Comment: The principles from that link remain the same regardless of EF version. Use an `IMyContext` interface that exposes `IDbSet<>` properties and mock those as `FakeDbSet<>`

Comment: @AlexG So I will need to create implementations of the Get IQueryably expressions and let the mock handle the non query related methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although DBSet implements IQueryable, IDbSet... the object generated by the mock engine is not implementing them.

A possible solution is using a Mocking framework that supports building mocks that implement many interfaces like the one pointed out in another thread (Substitute):
[Mocking DBSet, EF Model First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516543/mocking-dbset-ef-model-first)

Here you have an utility function to build a mocked DBSet which data is stored on a generic list:

```
public static DbSet<T> BuildMockedDbSet<T>(List<T> data) where T : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> queryable = data.AsQueryable();
        DbSet<T> fakeDbSet = Substitute.For<DbSet<T>, IQueryable<T>>();
        ((IQueryable<T>)fakeDbSet).Provider.Returns(queryable.Provider);
        ((IQueryable<T>)fakeDbSet).Expression.Returns(queryable.Expression);
        ((IQueryable<T>)fakeDbSet).ElementType.Returns(queryable.ElementType);
        ((IQueryable<T>)fakeDbSet).GetEnumerator().Returns(queryable.GetEnumerator());
        fakeDbSet.AsNoTracking().Returns(fakeDbSet);
        return fakeDbSet;
    }
```

Hope it helps.