# Mocking DbSet.toList

Tags: c#, testing, moq

I want to mock the method `DbSet.toList` but I get always a exception because the `toList` method is declared in `IEnumerable`.

Test method SocialSWT.Tests.Repository.RepositoryTest.GetCallsListOfEntities threw exception: 
System.NotSupportedException: Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object: foo => foo.ToList()

`dbSet.Setup(foo => foo.ToList()).Returns(mockList);`

Comment: `ToList` is an extension method. You have to check how your mocking framework supports mocking that type of methods.

Comment: You probably need to mock `DbSet` instead, methinks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Moq, there is no easy way mocking an extension method i.e ToList(). You need to abstract away the DbSet, i.e IDbSet and stub that instead. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463017/unit-testing-with-ef4-code-first-and-repository) SO question.